# YouTubeQuery API - NoClassDefFoundError - Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, noclassdeffounderror

I am a Java guy, recently started exploring Android, I was working on Youtube Data API with in android to query the youtube videos.

I have added the following jars in my project dependency as an external jars.

- activation.jar
- gdata-client-1.0.jar
- gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar
- gdata-core-1.0.jar
- gdata-youtube-2.0.jar
- mail.jar
- servlet-api.jar

The code compiles fine, however when I run the application in the emulator, I get this exception

```
AndroidRuntime(784): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeQuery
```

I am using eclipse Juno.

Here is my .classpath

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.36-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/lib/servlet-api.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Vishwas/gdata-samples.java-1.47.1/gdata/java/lib/gdata-client-1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Vishwas/gdata-samples.java-1.47.1/gdata/java/lib/gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Vishwas/gdata-samples.java-1.47.1/gdata/java/lib/gdata-core-1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Vishwas/gdata-samples.java-1.47.1/gdata/java/lib/gdata-youtube-2.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Vishwas/Downloads/activation.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Vishwas/Downloads/mail.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/activation.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Thanks

Comment: did you put jars in libs folder? if you do that eclipse should reckognize them automatically, also do you have import statement at the top of your class import com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeQuery ?

Comment: Yeah, I already tried adding it to libs folder and yes, import is there! Nothing is helping me to get past this error.

Comment: maybe you have to define it in your manifest file also

Comment: Can you paste your `.classpath` file?

Comment: Please have a look, I have edited my post with .classpath file.

Comment: vodich, can  you please let me know what do you mean by define it in manifest? Just curious, as I am new to android,  Isn't it enough to just add it as a library and in build path?

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me finally!!

Here is what I did.

1) Removed all the external jars I added through, Properties -> JavaBuildPath -> Libraries
2) Added all the jars to libs folder directly.

and it worked like a charm.  I am still not sure, why it didn't take the jars when I added it as external jar.

Here is how my latest .classparth!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/activation.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/android-support-v4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/gdata-client-1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/gdata-youtube-2.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/mailapi.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/servlet-api.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Thanks